# windows batch file scripting - keep formatting in html

Tags: html, scripting, batch-file, cmd

I'm currently trying to write a simple batch script that will run a series of windows commands and output them nicely into a single html file.

the command im running for example, is `netsh firewall show config`, Looks something like this:

```
Domain profile configuration (current):
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Operational mode                  = Enable
Exception mode                    = Enable
Multicast/broadcast response mode = Enable
Notification mode                 = Enable
Service configuration for Domain profile:
Mode     Customized  Name
```

Notice the nice spacing used that makes it easy to see?

I'm trying to keep that in the HTML file that i create. So far, i have a simple batch script as follows:

```
@echo off

echo ^<font face="courier new" size="2"^>^ >>index.html
netsh firewall show config >> netsh
type netsh >>index.html
```

When that spools to an index.html file, the resultant output looks something like this:

```
Domain profile configuration (current): -----------------------------------------------       
 -------------------- Operational mode = Enable Exception mode = Enable
 Multicast/broadcast     response mode = Enable Notification mode = Enable Service
 configuration for Domain profile: Mode Customized Name ------------------------------
------------------------------------ Enable No File and Printer Sharing Allowed\
programs configuration for Domain profile: Mode Traffic
```

So does anyone know how i can output the command in a nice way, such that the formatting is kept? Its really just a bunch of spaces and breaks.

Appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: have you considered using <pre /> ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`<pre>`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/pre) tag to retain the text layout:

```
@echo off
echo ^<pre^> >>index.html
netsh firewall show config >> index.html
echo ^</pre^> >>index.html
```